# How to generate type List<? super Number>?

Tags: java, generics, code-generation, sun-codemodel

Sun's `CodeModel` is able to generate `List<? extends Number>` by using `model.ref(List.class).narrow(model.ref(Number.class).wildcard())`.

However, I've searched the documentation and couldn't find a way to generate `List<? super Number>`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot be done as far as I see.

You can track this issue https://java.net/jira/browse/CODEMODEL-11

Also see the comment at line 52 here http://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/20492343. It's a TODO.

If it's any help, maybe you can accomplish what you are trying to do by generating a List of a concrete super type, like `model.ref(List.class).narrow(model.ref(Number.class)._extends())`.